# HTML5 canvas updating a color of an existing line - possible?

Tags: html5-canvas

I am new to html5 and trying to get a handle on the fundamentals.

I'm wondering once I draw a line (say in black), is it possible for me to get a "pointer" to that line using the canvas's context and subsequently update the color of that line? Does that operation make sense in html5 land? Or do I have to redraw a new line on the exact same spot with the new color?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. It's canvas, not *really* HTML5. True the tag is in HTML5, but what you're talking about is more specific. 2. It depends if you save a reference. Can you provide more detail as to what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to redraw your line because canvas/context does not "remember" where it drew your line.

The common design pattern is to "remember" the line in a javascript object:

```
var myLine={x0:10,y1:20,x1:100,y1:50};
```

Then you can redraw the remembered line with a new color:

```
context.strokeStyle=myNewColor;
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(myLine.x0,myLine.y0);
context.lineTo(myLine.x1,myLine.y1);
context.stroke();
```

Another possible glitch.

Canvas will automatically anti-alias all of its path drawings.  That means canvas may add anti-aliasing pixels to your first line which will remain even if you overwrite that first line.

A common design pattern for canvas drawings is to "remember" all drawings and then completely erase & redraw all the remembered objects to the canvas.

A useful new feature is being added to Html Canvas...

In near future versions of canvas, there will be a Path Object built into the context that will "remember" path objects for you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function myColor(){
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.strokeStyle = document.getElementById("colorChange").value;
  ctx.moveTo(50,50);
  ctx.lineTo(100,100);
  ctx.stroke()
}

window.onload = myColor()
```

```html
<canvas id = "myCanvas" width = "400" height = "400"></canvas>
<input type = "color" id = "colorChange" oninput = myColor() value = "#ff0000">
```